# Spring Instantiate a component dynamically inside a method

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to instantiate a component inside a method, to be more precise inside a rest method. I need a new instance of the component every time the rest method is invoked

```
@Validated
@RestController
@RequestMapping("test")
public class Test {

    @GetMapping
    public String test() {
        // Spring equivalent of
        // TestComponent component = new TestComponent();
        return component.uuid();
    }

}
```

My component is defined like this

```
@Scope
@Component
@Transactional
public class TestComponent {

    private EntityManager entityManager;
    private UUID randomUUID;

    @Autowired
    public TestComponent(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
        this.randomUUID = UUID.randomUUID();
    }

    public String uuid() {
        // entityManager transactional stuff
        return randomUUID.toString();
    }

}
```

I tried to use a factory method but the instance was not transactional, I tried to use `ApplicationContext.getBean` but the instance was a singleton. How can I instantiate my component dynamically whenever I need it?

I'm using Spring 3.0.0-RC1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use different scopes to define the life cycle and visibility of that bean in the context. The default scope is `Singleton`, which means only one instance is created.

In your particular case, I think that you should choose between:

- `Prototype` - creates a new instance every time a request for that specific bean is made. It can be defined with `@Scope("prototype")` annotation.
- `Request` - each HTTP request has its own instance, only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring `ApplicationContext`. It can be defined with `@RequestScope` annotation.

To find out more details about all supported scopes, check [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-scopes).

Comment: @Scope("prototype") works fine! Is instantiating the component every time with ApplicationContext.getBean okay or is there a better way?

Comment: That's actually not good approach for dependency injection. There are multiple ways to inject dependencies. I suggest you to read [the blog post](https://reflectoring.io/constructor-injection/).